# Is there a way to add Bots in a multiplayer game of Call of Duty?

Tags: call-of-duty-united-offensive

Game: Call of Duty: United offensive.

I like the multiplayer in Call of duty so much. But is there a way to add Bots in a game like we add bots in Quake3Arena? I can't find any straight forward approach to achieve it. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im almost certain Call of Duty didn't add this function. Have you seen them on another server?

EDIT: Just had a look. Looks like they didn't, however you might be able to add bots by using [this](http://callofduty.filefront.com/file/Tallys_MP_Bot_Mod;53806).

However it does warn that they will be stupid and not useful. Very unlike the Bots in Counter Strike.

Comment: No. I haven't seen this in any server. Just curious!

Comment: I didn't think so, but couldnt 100% confirm as Ive never played UO.

But Hope this helps? If not let me know!

Comment: The link in the above answer is for COD2 bots, not Call of Duty 1